# Django Rest - How to retreive more than one record from API and pass all of them to loop though in template?

Tags: python, django, rest

Most of tutorials that I found was about creating APIs and not about using existing ones. I know that I am missing some huge, crucial thing. Could you please point me to it?

I want to receive from OMDB API several hits after posting title to search. My current code in views.py looks like this:

```
class MoviesList(APIView):

    def get(self, APIView):
        movies = Movie.objects.all()
        serializer = MovieSerializer(movies, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):

        title = request.POST.get("Title")

        api_key = "111111"
        url = f"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t={title}&type=movie&apikey={api_key}"
        response = requests.get(url)

        serializer = MovieSerializer(data=response.json())
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            movie_details = {
                'title': response.json()['Title'],
                'genre': response.json()['Genre'],
                'plot': response.json()['Plot'],
                'year': response.json()['Year'],
                'runtime': response.json()['Runtime'],
            }
            return render(request, 'movie_database/results.html', movie_details)
        else:
            print(serializer.errors)
            print("Something went wrong.")
```

And it is working. With this code I receive one result and I can pass that to my template. And use values like "title" and "genre".

But I know that by changing in "url" t={title} to s={title} I can receive 10 results (I tested it in browser by hand and it is working).

EDIT:

When I change this letter "t" to "s" I receive this error:

```
AssertionError at /MoviesList/

Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

How I can utilize that and loop through them in my template? After looking for over 1 hour for answer I know that my basic approach is wrong but I am unable to find proper one right now.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use Django Rest Framework for the task? If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is 1. Fetch input from the user which specifies a movie title search string (you seem to be using a POST request when collecting this info, but a GET request seems more appropriate) 2. Fetch data from the OMDB database, using its API 3. Process the API response data 4. Present the response data/search results to the user. Base Django seems much more appropriate for this than DRF. DRF is for building your own API, and you don't seem to be doing that here.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) documentation to loop over list in templates.

Plus why are you receiving APIView in get method!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check this get. But I am using "post" methon to actually post the title that I am looking for. And when I change this "t" to "s" then I receive error "AssertionError at /MoviesList/

Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`"

Comment: There are multiple mistakes you are doing here.
1) You need to return something from the view; which is mentioned in the error, as you are returning nothing from the else clause. 2) serializer.is_valid() is returning False because your serializer has to deal with one object. If you want to deal with list of objects which is 's' in your case, you need to pass many=True argument while initializing the serializer